# Calling a python analytics library from javascript/React.js

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm very new to writing java script code and and have recently joined a team that are building a website in React.js (in docker containers etc.). One of my roles is to create an analytics library in python that can be called to provide the data to be displayed. Can someone tell me what the best technology for doing this is?

I have been told that the best way is to use Flask but in other places on the web I have seen mention of AJAX. As I have no knowledge of either of these packages a push in the right direct would be really beneficial. At the moment the calls are likely to be synchronous calls but async updates are almost certainly going to come along at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Flask`, if your application is going to a small one. If you think your application / project is going to be a huge one, you can use use `Django` framework.

Both the Python Liraries support API / REST. For using REST with Flask you can refer [here](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask). For using REST with Django you can refer [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: Can you give me an understanding of "small" and "huge"? I would say that the site may, at it peak have 100 pages with each page having charts, tables, text etc. Also, are you saying that AJAX is a red herring?

Comment: Small: less users, less computation, only few interactions with the server. Huge: needs scaability, need to use worker threads, multiple clients, frequent hits,

Comment: OK. Thanks that is pretty clear. It's likely that we will have quite a few users in the longer term so I guess Django is probably the way to go